# Rails and mysql DB stack level too deep

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am learning ror and in my controller I am trying to access the tests table. Here is the code in my controller

```
class ExecutionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @testcases = Tests.all
    end
end
```

Here is my view

```
<h1>Hello, Wortld!</h1>
<hr />
<% @testcases.each do |t| %>
    <p><%= t.package %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I run the server and try to load the page I get an error page that talks about the stack being too long. If I load up the rails console, I can see the tests database is there but for the life of me I cannot get my webapp to talk to it.

```
➜  automation_metrics_tool git:(master) ✗ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0.rc1)
2.1.1 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["execution_notes", "jira_defects", "requirements", "schema_migrations",    
"store_environments", "stores", "test_executions", "test_requirements", "test_types",    
"testexec_jiradefects", "tests", "zephyr_testcases"]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: could you put the `Tests` class implementation ?

Comment: @artmees ExecutionsController is it. Could it be that is the problem? Should the controller have the same name as db table?

Comment: no i was asking about the model... isn't there a model named `Test` defined in `class Test` ?

Comment: Yes I have a model but it was called tests instead of test

Comment: Could you pat the implementation of the `Tests` model ?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails names of the ActiveRecord models are in singular while the real tables in the database are in plural. So in your example you should call `User.all` instead of `Users.all`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had one of the table fields called class. Soon as I changed my model from class to clazz, re-imported db, everything was good.